# unable to get the list values from union query in xamarin

Tags: sql, sqlite, linq, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get the list of distinct ID's by comparing two tables.
Here is my query:

```
public List<int> GetDistinctCustomerIDs(List<int> ticketIDs)
    {
        string tIDs = string.Join(",", ticketIDs);
        var strSql = "Select distinct a.CustomerID";
        strSql += " From Ticket a ";
        strSql += " Left Join CustomerContact b On a.CalledInByID = b.ContactID";
        strSql += " Where a.TicketID in (?) And b.ContactID is null";
        strSql += " UNION";
        strSql += " Select distinct a.CustomerID";
        strSql += " From Ticket a";
        strSql += " Left Join CustomerContact b On a.ForemanID = b.ContactID";
        strSql += " Where a.TicketID in (?) And b.ContactID is null";
        List<int> IDs = connection.Query<int>(strSql, tIDs).ToList();

        return IDs;
    }
```

I'm getting the expected result count as 1 but its value is always 0 which is not. When I run the query in sqlite browser it shows correct result but not in my code.

Any help?

Comment: Observation:  the query has two parameter substitutions (?) and only one parameter "argument" (tIDs).

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I tried this, but still it its value is 0 like list[0] = 0

Comment: It should work in xamarin if it works in sqlite browser. Double check the data in your table and the parameter tIDs.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT 
Select distinct a.CustomerID From Ticket a  
Left Join CustomerContact b On a.CalledInByID = b.ContactID 
Where a.TicketID = 147934 And b.ContactID is null 
UNION Select distinct a.CustomerID From Ticket a 
Left Join CustomerContact b On a.ForemanID = b.ContactID 
Where a.TicketID = 147934 And b.ContactID is null
--- this is query i'm testing in both, but still I'm not understand why it is not working in my code when converting it to list

Comment: Can you try replace the tIDs with a real number in your  code to see if it works?

Comment: I tried it didn't work. So I created a test class with an int variable. And changed List<int> to list<class>. Then I can see the expected results.